# Plotly Dash: Uncaught (in promise) Error after upgrading dash to 2.7.1

Tags: javascript, python, plotly-dash

I have a Dash App running inside a Flask App. I am seeing a bunch of errors in the console after upgrading dash to `2.7.1`

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received


Uncaught (in promise) Error: There is already a source with this ID

at r.addSource (async-plotlyjs.js:2:1020888)
    at i.addSource (async-plotlyjs.js:2:1219363)
    at l.addSource (async-plotlyjs.js:2:2988732)
    at async-plotlyjs.js:2:2989736
    at h (async-plotlyjs.js:2:2989770)
    at l.update (async-plotlyjs.js:2:2990100)
    at b.updateData (async-plotlyjs.js:2:2338377)
    at async-plotlyjs.js:2:2336961
```

[image: error-ss]

I do not see any errors in the application logs. What is the error? Any suggestions on where to look / troubleshoot?

Application code:

tab1.py

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'x': [1, 2, 3],
                   'Lat': [37.774322, 37.777035, 37.773033],
                   'Long': [-122.489761, -122.485555, -122.491220]
                 }) 

layout = html.Div(
                   dcc.Graph(id="map"),
                   dcc.Input(id="inp")
                 )

@app.callback(
              Output('map','figure'),
              Input('inp','value')
             )
def fin(val):
    
    # do something

    data = []
    
    data.append({

                                 "type": "scattermapbox",
                                 "lat": df["Lat"],
                                 "lon": df["Long"],
                                 "name": "Location",
                                 "showlegend": False,
                                 "hoverinfo": "text",
                                 "mode": "markers",
                                 "clickmode": "event+select",
                                 "customdata": df.loc[:,cd_cols].values,
                                 "marker": {
                                            "symbol": "circle",
                                            "size": 8,
                                            "opacity": 0.7,
                                            "color": "black"
                                           }
                                 }
                   )

      layout = {

                     "autosize": True,
                     "hovermode": "closest",
                     "mapbox": {

                         "accesstoken": MAPBOX_KEY,
                         "bearing": 0,
                         "center": {
                             "lat": xxx,
                             "lon": xxx
                         },
                         "pitch": 0,
                         "zoom": zoom,
                         "style": "satellite-streets",

                     },

                    
        }

        return ({'data': data, 'layout': layout})
```

application.py

```
import dash
import flask
from dash import dcc, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import os

# External stylesheets

SANDSTONE = "xxxxx"

external_stylesheets = [
    SANDSTONE,
    {
        'href': 'custom.css',
        'rel': 'stylesheet'
    },
    {
        'href': 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css',
        'rel': 'stylesheet'
    }
]

application = dash.Dash(__name__,
                        requests_pathname_prefix='/dashboard/',
                        #serve_locally = False,
                        suppress_callback_exceptions = True,
                        meta_tags=[
                            {"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}
                        ],
                        external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets,
               )


server = application.server

# Title the app.
application.title = "Stroom - Platform Demo"
```

index.py

```
# In[32]:

import pandas as pd
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash import dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html
#import dash_design_kit as ddk
import plotly as py
from plotly import graph_objs as go
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import flask
from application import application
import os
from tabs import comps, analysis, deals, returns
from pages import home
import traceback

# In[8]:
server = application.server

# App Layout
application.layout = html.Div([

                        # header
                        html.Div([

                            html.Div(

                                html.Img(src='https://ss.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/logo-black.png',height="100%"),
                                style={"float":"right",
                                       "width":"170px",
                                       "height":"100px",
                                       "margin-top":"-84px"
                                       }
                            ),

                            html.Div(

                                [
                                    html.H4("Market Intelligence", style={"textAlign":"center"}),
                                    html.Hr(),
                                    dbc.Nav(
                                        [
                                            dbc.NavLink("Tab1", href="/tab1", active="partial"),
                                            dbc.NavLink("Tab2", href="/tab2", active="partial"),
                                           

                                        ],
                                        vertical=True,
                                        fill=True,
                                        pills=True,
                                    ),
                                ],

                                style = {
                                    "position": "fixed",
                                    "top": 0,
                                    "left": 0,
                                    "bottom": 0,
                                    "width": "10rem",
                                    "padding": "1rem 1rem",
                                    "background-color": "#f8f9fa",
                                },

                            ),

                            dcc.Location(id='url'),

                            html.Div(id='page-content'),

                            # Store component
                            dcc.Store(id="comps-store", storage_type="local"),

                            # Store component for graphs
                            dcc.Store(id="modal-store", storage_type="local"),

                            ],

                        )

])



# Render page content
@application.callback(Output("page-content", "children"),
              [
                Input('url', 'pathname')
              ]
             )
def display_content(pathname):

    print(pathname)

    if pathname in ["/","/dashboard/","/dashboard2"]:
        return tab1.layout

    elif pathname == "/comps":
        return comps.layout

    else:
        return dash.no_update
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_required
import sys
import os
sys.path.append("..") # Adds higher directory to python modules path.
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from index import application as dashApp

import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


database = 'login'

server_auth = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)

server_auth.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ["pwd"]
server_auth.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(os.environ["user"],os.environ["pwd"],os.environ["host"], database)

# Update this for Production
server_auth.config['TESTING'] = True

# init SQLAlchemy so we can use it later in our models
db = SQLAlchemy(server_auth)

db.init_app(server_auth)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
login_manager.init_app(server_auth)

from .models import users, init_db
init_db() # created mysql tables

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
    return users.query.get(int(user_id))

# blueprint for auth routes in our app
from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
server_auth.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

# blueprint for non-auth parts of app
from .main import main as main_blueprint
server_auth.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

# from .app import appdash as dash_blueprint
# app.register_blueprint(dash_blueprint)
# return server_auth

@server_auth.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return redirect('/dashboard')

app = DispatcherMiddleware(server_auth,
                           {'/dashboard': dashApp.server})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_simple('0.0.0.0', 80, app, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```

Comment: That's a JavaScript error, unrelated to Flask nor Python.  Also, that trace is impossible to debug because it appears to be from a minified file, either use a sourcemap or use the debug (non-minified) version.

Comment: @metatoaster I have added a screenshot of the lines throwing the exception.

Comment: Searching for "There is already a source with this ID" will bring up some relevant results. The problem is likely to do with some configuration file or something unrelated that reused a same ID somewhere, but that's only something you have access to so you will need to do some extensive debugging.

Comment: Can you provide more code about how you initialise it or something? We can assess where the error come from, but not what may cause it without more code

Comment: @SirPeople I have update the post with some application code, so you can check out how i initialize etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to a bug in the `React Developer Tools` browser extension.  Disable it and it should go away.